# Unknown server tag 'asp:ListView'

Tags: asp.net, exception

Hello i just deployed my application to the remote server.
I am receiving this error :

```
Server Error in '/please_god' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'asp:ListView'.

Source Error: 


Line 55:     <font color="brown" size="+1">New Posting(Messages)</font><br />
Line 56: 
Line 57:     <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"  
Line 58:         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
Line 59:         <LayoutTemplate>
```

Can somebody help me out why am i receiving this error when using `listview`.
I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 and it works fine on my local machine.

Comment: Can you post lines 50 through 60 of that source file?

Comment: looks like a problem with web.config. search the web for this error message, you will get plenty of hits.

Comment: Are you sure that the server runs at the same version as your site ? (eg the server is configured at version 4 and your site the same)

Comment: Have you correctly defined the `asp` namespace in that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are targeting / have installed the correct version of the .net framework? You'll need to have 3.5 + targeted.

Answer (score 2):

Add that:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

to web config in case it does not exists